# In Python, I have installed OpenCV using pip but the site packages folder has a different colour and I cannot import installed libraries. PyCharm IDE

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, pycharm, opencv, python

I have an issue when I want to import the libraries that I have installed using pip in python. When I go to site packages, the libraries are there but they have a different colour than the rest of the of other folders. It is greyed out as a result I cannot use them. You can see the attached image.  Please help!

Comment: It looks like you may have forgotten to attach the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is not visible:

There are a few things you can try out:

1. Check if you are using Virtual environment and the project interpreter from the Pycharm's File--> Settings
2. If you are using the Virtual Environment for the project, you will be able to install individually the required packages for the project,go to File--> Settings-->Project-->Project Interpreter(Here all the already installed packages for the current virtual environment will be visible).If your package is not present in the list, click on '+', search for the required package and install.

Comment: Thank you this worked! Quick question, by installing the packages using the IDE, is it installing from github or from site packages? Why does the environment not "see" the installed packages, am I installing it incorrectly or there are read and write issues?